Crop an image taken in a known focal length, to get it in other focal length
Say that i have an image of 2560 x 1920, that is taken with a focal length of 2.8mm.
Is it possible to crop the image so that it corresponds to another focal length of say 94mm, and if so, how do i calculate the pixel width x height to crop the image to ?

See related questions: What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?, What is the difference between zooming in and cropping?, Photo-SE search: crop image focal length

2.8mm??? or 28mm.

@rafael 2.8mm would be normal in  smartphone, which is also consistent with the 4/3 aspect ratio and low resoltuion of the sensor.

Yes, since the spacial relationship of objects in the scene is dictated only by the perspective (distance), you can crop a wider recorded FOV for the same resulting image composition as if a longer FL was used instead.
You can use a field of view calculator to determine the relative amount of the scene that would remain if a longer FL was used. Or, double the FL is half the FOV.
The only issue is that the declared FL is often a result of rounding and not exact.

While fundamentally I agree with this, the example in the question is going from 2.8mm to 94mm or a factor of just about 32, at which point the fraction of the original image which remains is going to be so small as to be essentially unusable.

@PhilipKendall, yes, I specifically avoided getting into discussion of resolution and pixel size, etc... I figured anything using a 2.8mm lens is a very small sensor with a high crop factor and IDK what the 94mm equivalent would be (or intended). It just makes a simple answer a mess.
